# specifying multipe method parameters in web api2 attribute routing

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am converting some of my services to Web API2 and I have some functions which take 2 or 3 parameters. How are those routing attributes constructed?

When I call the function from the old service in javascript its

```
data: { "symboltype": symboltype, "symbol": symb, "requestDate": dDate}
```

I've tried the following routing attribute among other variations, which dont work

```
    <HttpGet()> _
    <Route("getsinglerangeprojection/{symboltype:int,symbol,requestdate}")> _
    Public Function GetSingleRangeProjection(ByVal symboltype As Integer,
                                             ByVal symbol As String,
                                             ByVal requestDate As String) As ProjectedRange
        ...code here
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is they all get separated by slashes as shown below

```
 <HttpGet()> _
 <Route("getsinglerangeprojection/symboltype/{symboltype:int}/symbol/{symbol}/requestdate/{requestDate:datetime}")> _
 Public Function GetSingleRangeProjection(ByVal symboltype As Integer,
                                         ByVal symbol As String,
                                         ByVal requestDate As String) As ProjectedRange
    ...code here
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model to represent your data like this

```
public class MyData
    {
        public string symboltype { get; set; }

        public string symbol { get; set; }

        public DateTime requestData { get; set; }
    }
```

And change your method to use the model or **JObject** as the parameter.

Finally, post the whole json object as a string

data:JSON.stringify({ "symboltype": symboltype, "symbol": symb, "requestDate": dDate});

Hope this help.

Comment: The javascript works fine as is, that wasn't the question. The question is how to specify multiple parameters in attribute routing

Comment: Apparently, you couldn't reach the API method. If you don't like that approach, you can you a query string like http://localhost:3557/api/products?symboltype=1&symb=2&requestDate=3